# Google Cloud role to allow pulling container from GCR

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

What role should I assign to my service account in Google Cloud in order to allow pilling containers from Google Cloud Registry (GCR)?

I tried `Artifact Registry Reader` and `Cloud Build Viewer`, but it didn't help. 
Still getting: `"docker login: denied: Permission denied"` error message.

If I use `Project Editor` Role, it works. Is there something more granular?

Comment: Artifact Registry reader is fine, but Cloud Build Viewer is not suffiient. There is a role "Cloud Build Service Account" which can perform the build. This role will not allow your user or service acccount to edit the build process but you can pull the docker image if it is part of your build pipeline. Can you try and tell me if it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control) provides you the right level of permission that you require.

For instance, `Storage object viewer` is the correct role to set for pulling an image